# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined jade to html

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, template-engine, ejs

When I'm converting my jade to html, I'm getting this error in index.jade:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/runtime.js:231
  throw err;
        ^
TypeError: index.jade:50
    48|                             i.fa.fa-plus-square
    49|                             |  Add new Question
  > 50|                     li
    51|                         a(runat='server', href='/q/about')
    52|                             i.fa.fa-question-circle
    53|                             |  About

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at jade_debug.unshift.lineno (eval at <anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:216:8), <anonymous>:331:31)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:216:8), <anonymous>:428:4)
```

The index.jade at line number 50 looks like:

```
.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top
        .container
            .navbar-header
                button.navbar-toggle(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='.navbar-collapse')
                    span.icon-bar
                    span.icon-bar
                    span.icon-bar
                a.navbar-brand(runat='server', href='/')
                    i.fa.fa-home
                    |  The Strings Project
            .navbar-collapse.collapse
                ul.nav.navbar-nav
                    li
                        a(runat='server', href='/q')
                            i.fa.fa-list-ul
                            |  Questions
                    li
                        a(runat='server', href='/q/new')
                            i.fa.fa-plus-square
                            |  Add new Question
                    li
                        a(runat='server', href='/q/about')
                            i.fa.fa-question-circle
                            |  About
                    li
                        a(runat='server', href='#')
                            i.fa.fa-phone-square
                            |  Contact
```

Kindly suggest me where I have gone wrong? I'm using ejs as my template engine and running nodejs on an express server.

Here's the picture with line numbers as well:
[image]

Comment: why is this tagged ejs are you using ejs anywhere?

Comment: Yes I used ejs to render HTML engine

Comment: is the page rendering without that ul.nav.navbar-nav ?